# Why is the site's domain unix.SE?

Tags: discussion, domain

I'm not advocating a rename here, really, just curious. It seems like out of the "unix and linux" scope advertised, the vast majority of the questions are either Linux or generic *nix. What was the rationale for picking unix for the subdomain over linux, or perhaps nix?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69623/rename-unix-se-to-opensource-se)

Comment: @badp: Not really. I saw that, and I have no idea why someone thought "open source" would be a good catchall term for unix/linux/*nix. I am fully aware of the scope of the site.

Comment: lunix would be great! for anyone who has read that [adequacy article](http://www.adequacy.org/stories/2001.12.2.42056.2147.html).

Comment: Here I outlined the rationale for changing the subdomain to linux: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5892/233262

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We didn't have any say in that, the domain was assigned, and I imagine whoever handled it didn't put a lot of thought into it (that was back before we realized the [domain would be permanent](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/) -- when our beta started it was still the plan to [buy top-level domains](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) when sites launched). Some sites have multiple subdomains in case of confusion, and https://linux.stackexchange.com/ will work as well; they probably just made the primary one https://unix.stackexchange.com/ because Unix appears first in the name

Answer (score 5):

I find unix-SE excellent, in a sense that the site is about the Unix family of OSes. Linux is more a subset of Unix.

Comment: Linux isn't really a subset of unix. It's better described as unix-like (*nix or un*x); those are better names for the family of OSes we're talking about here, even if they're not good domain names.

Comment: @Jef, I said *more a subset*, not *a subset*. This was in a sense of Unix as a family, much as I'd say __x86 family__ if I was referring to both Intel and AMD parts, instead of referring to AMD parts as __x86-like__.

Comment: I get that, and I know no one would say unix is part of the linux family, but I'm much more used to hearing unix-like, *nix, un*x, and maybe unix family than I am "Unix OSes". I know I'm getting a little pedantic, but there you are.

Comment: @Jef, This reminds of a case of OSes like Ubuntu and Linux Mint... what to classify them as. Some guys say they are Debian, and I was thinking maybe Debian-like, but this is limited -- it just implies Debian derivatives. I now think that __Debian family__ is better (instead of the awkward __Debian and derivatives__).

Comment: Yeah, it can definitely be hard to describe things, especially in a world as fragmented as *nix and all the associated software, and especially in a single word. (And it's even worse with Ubuntu, where quite a lot of users probably don't even know about Debian.)

Comment: Linux is **NOT** a UNIX, as opposed to Mac OS X, which *is* a UNIX.

Comment: @polemon: Yeah, but it's family. Think of it as an adopted child. It acts like Unix family because it was raised by it.

Answer (score 2):

"unix" is a widely recognized name, and even most of the users here know that 'UNIX(tm)-like' topics will apply to their situation.

This is not simply a SE problem, but the entire community has a problem coming up for the magic name that describes this the vast ecosystem of questions posed by "[users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq)".

The current and potential users of this site use Linux-based-operating systems, MacOSX, FreeBSD, Solaris, NanoBSD, OpenWRT and more. These operating systems, as well as concepts like '[Posix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posix)', share a lot in common. Users will have many of the same questions, and most of the answers here will often apply to many different operating systems.

Would a name like "linux.stackexchange.com" be better? Wouldn't that exclude FreeBSD, Solaris & MacOSX users? Just to make a point: 'Linux' is a kernel (or maybe it's a project?), [not an operating system](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.html). Would questions regarding bash-shell or be appropriate on "linux.stackexchange.com"?

unix.stackexchange.com is better then a name like "gnu-linux_FreeBSD_Solaris_MacOSX_Posix_and_other_related_operating_systems.stackexchange.com".

'nix.stackexchange.com' sounds cool to me, but I'm sure it would be [confusing to many  people](http://www.google.com/search?q=nix). A Lice Shampoo?

Whatever the answer, it needs to fit into the limitations of the DNS system. I would love a name like 'un*x.stackexchange.com', but that just won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The real reason is that a lot of software disliked the original domain name, `*nix.stackexchange.com`. Honest!

Answer (score 1):

I remember people suggesting things like *kernelpanic.com* or other unix-error related name. Personally, I'd like to see that it'd get its own domain name.

Don't know if that's still possible, though.

Comment: That was stopped soon after the first SE site was launched; see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/). In theory we can try to get a separate domain once we have huge amounts of traffic, but I'm not too worried about it

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, [unix.se](http://unix.se/Interview_with_Dennis_Ritchie) exists.

Comment: unix.SE was an abbreviation of unix.stackexchange. No one was suggesting unix.se as the exact domain name.

Comment: Yeah, but it's confusing. And not confusing in a good way — it's parochial and plays up an unfortunate we-are-the-world clique-like aspect of Stack Exchange. Much, much better to use something like unix-SE as shorthand.

Comment: @mattdm [Can StackOverflow Inc. purchase the .se top-level domain?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73836/can-stackoverflow-inc-purchase-the-se-top-level-domain)

Comment: @Gilles — poor Sweden!

Comment: @Gilles: Great.  I'm surprised no one has suggesting suing the current owners of wanted *.se domains because they were squatting in the way of the one true use.